# How to make Nuget.config for my custom repository?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I must use [Infragistics](https://www.infragistics.com/) for my project.
This is the current situation(Package Sources)

[image]

It seems that I haven't explained my intentions. I tried to delete Nuget.org from my NuGet Package Manager( commit and sync in VS 2019). My Nuget.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!--To inherit the global NuGet package sources remove the <clear/> line below -->
    <add key="Infragistics" value="http://localhost:8624/nuget/Infragistics/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

With this setup,my App Center build fails

```
2021-09-22T10:02:09.7806767Z   GET http://localhost:8624/nuget/Infragistics/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
2021-09-22T10:02:09.7807611Z Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://localhost:8624/nuget/Infragistics/FindPackagesById()?id='Infragistics.Web.Documents.Core'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
2021-09-22T10:02:09.7810957Z An error occurred while sending the request.
2021-09-22T10:02:09.7811349Z   Unable to connect to the remote server
```

Does anyone have any idea what I should change?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file

Comment: @TheGeneral Ha!

Comment: @DavidG :P I'm leaving it, 2 is always better than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Infragistics documentation. You can simply reference the Nuget feed instead of using the local source.

Reference -> https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/nuget-feeds#adding_infragistics_feed